# Unable to download mongovue

Tags: mongodb, mongovue

As of checking today, it looks like http://www.mongovue.com/, is down.

Was wondering if anyone knew if this was being deprecated or an appropriate transition plan if that is not the case?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Software tool recommendation is off-topic for StackOverflow. You could try the [Software Recommendations StackExchange](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) instead but I expect only the developer can answer if they are planning to update or open source their product. For some alternative clients I would suggest checking out the "GUI" category on the [MongoDB Tools](http://mongodb-tools.com) directory.

Comment: Would it help if I reworded it to be: "Am having issues downloading mongovue, help?"

Comment: on a related note, is there a way to "move" a question between stack exchanges?

Comment: Issues downloading Mongovue are still a better question for the application publisher and not [on-topic as a programming question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for StackOverflow. Moderators can migrate questions between StackExchanges, but this seems discretionary versus closing as off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have had good luck with [RoboMongo](http://robomongo.org).  It is free and appears to be well supported by the community.